# Advanced Theorems List from ntheorem Documentation throws errors

Tags: lists, theorems, ntheorem

I have defined my theorems as follows

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathtools,framed}
\usepackage{enumitem} % einfacher Nummerierung ver√§ndern
\usepackage{listofitems} % für Farben für Kapitel

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Theoreme%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[thmmarks,framed,thref]{ntheorem} % [thmmarks] guarantees endmarks

%theorem
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=subsection]{thm}{Satz} 
{{colback=\mycolors[\thesection]!5},
{colframe=\mycolors[\thesection]!95!black},
fonttitle=\scshape\bfseries,
before skip=15pt plus 2pt,after skip=15pt plus 2pt}{th}

\setsepchar{,}
\readlist\mycolors{amaranth,blue,orange,purple}

\newcounter{counter} 
\numberwithin{counter}{subsection}

% defn
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremprework{\medbreak}
\theorempostwork{\medbreak}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremheaderfont{\kern-5mm\bfseries} 
\theoremindent=5mm
\def\theoremframecommand{\colorbox{\mycolors[\thesection]!10}}
\newshadedtheorem{defn}[counter]{\textsc{Definition}}

%lemma
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremprework{%
\def\FrameCommand{
{\color{\mycolors[\thesection]}{\hspace{-8pt}\vrule width 2pt     \hspace{6pt}}}}
\medbreak}
\theorempostwork{\medbreak}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremheaderfont{\kern-5mm\normalfont\bfseries} 
\theoremindent0.5cm
\newframedtheorem{lemma}[counter]{Lemma}

\definecolor{amaranth}{HTML}{a82337}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{BF7F00}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{016FB9}
\definecolor{purple}{HTML}{603C96}

\newtheoremlisttype{tab}%
{\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}lrl@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}}%
{##1&##2&##3&##4\\}%
{\end{tabular*}}
\begin{document}
\section{first section}
\begin{lemma}[first lemma]
This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

oh, another lemma!

\begin{lemma}[second lemma]
This is a lemma, also.
\end{lemma}

oh, another lemma!

\begin{lemma}[third lemma]
This is a lemma, also.
\end{lemma}

oh, another lemma!

\begin{lemma}[fourth lemma]
This is a lemma, also.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}[another lemma]
This is a lemma, also.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}[another lemma]
This is a lemma, also.
\end{lemma}
\begin{lemma}[another lemma]
This is a lemma, also.
\end{lemma}
\begin{lemma}[another lemma]
This is a lemma, also.
\end{lemma}
\begin{lemma}[another lemma]
This is a lemma, also.
\end{lemma}        
\section{Alle wichtigen Definitionen und Lemmata}
\theoremlisttype{tab}
\listtheorems{defn,lemma}
\end{document}
```

Now I want to use the following extension from the ntheorem documentation, but counters pop up again :/
Bonus: How can I make a list of all theorems and lemmas?

Comment: Can you specify your question? Which extension of `ntheorem`? What is the desired result? What is wrong with the counters? You have already a list of all lemmata that are used in your example code.

Comment: The extension is the \newtheorentype. It come directly from the documentation of ntheorem and the desired result is the result from the documentation.

Comment: Do you mean `\newtheoremlisttype`? There are multiple examples in the [documentation](http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ntheorem/ntheorem.pdf). So please be more specific where someone should find the desired result. Give a page number or describe the result directly in the question.

Comment: Yes, I do. The example is found on the bottom of page 26 and the result on page 27, I copied the code from the documentation as last thing in my preamble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Adaptations:**

- removed: `\newcounter{counter}` and `\numberwithin{counter}{subsection}`
- added: `\theoremnumbering{arabic}` or `\theoremnumbering{greek}` (see page 17 of the [ntheorem documentation](http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ntheorem/ntheorem.pdf))
- changed: `\newframedtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[subsection]` to use subsection number + theoremnumbering
- added: new columntype `L` fot tabular, so long titles get a linebreak
- added: `defn` environments for testing the result
- note: use UTF8 coding as file encoding to preserve german umlauts. (see line 4)

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathtools,framed}
\usepackage{enumitem} % einfacher Nummerierung verändern
\usepackage{listofitems} % für Farben für Kapitel

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Theoreme%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[thmmarks,framed,thref]{ntheorem} % [thmmarks] guarantees endmarks

%theorem
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=subsection]{thm}{Satz} 
{{colback=\mycolors[\thesection]!5},
{colframe=\mycolors[\thesection]!95!black},
fonttitle=\scshape\bfseries,
before skip=15pt plus 2pt,after skip=15pt plus 2pt}{th}

\setsepchar{,}
\readlist\mycolors{amaranth,blue,orange,purple}

% defn
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremprework{\medbreak}
\theorempostwork{\medbreak}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremheaderfont{\kern-5mm\bfseries} 
\theoremindent=5mm
\def\theoremframecommand{\colorbox{\mycolors[\thesection]!10}}
\theoremnumbering{arabic} % <- NEW for arabic counter
\newshadedtheorem{defn}{\textsc{Definition}}[subsection] % subsection + arabic

%lemma
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremprework{%
\def\FrameCommand{
{\color{\mycolors[\thesection]}{\hspace{-8pt}\vrule width 2pt     \hspace{6pt}}}}
\medbreak}
\theorempostwork{\medbreak}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremheaderfont{\kern-5mm\normalfont\bfseries}
\theoremindent0.5cm
\theoremnumbering{greek} % <- NEW for greek counter
\newframedtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[subsection] % subsection + greek

\definecolor{amaranth}{HTML}{a82337}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{BF7F00}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{016FB9}
\definecolor{purple}{HTML}{603C96}


\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hspace{0pt}\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % linksbündig mit Breitenangabe

\newtheoremlisttype{tab}%
{\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}lrL{85mm}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}}%
{##1&##2&##3&##4\\}%
{\end{tabular*}}

\begin{document}
\section{first section}

\subsection{first subsection}

\begin{lemma}[first lemma]
    This is a lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}[second lemma with a very long title to get a linebreak in tabular]
    This is a lemma, also.
\end{lemma}

\begin{defn}[first theorem]
    This is a theorem, also.
\end{defn}

\begin{lemma}[third lemma]
    This is a lemma, also.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}[fourth lemma]
    This is a lemma, also.
\end{lemma}

\begin{defn}[second theorem]
    This is a theorem.
\end{defn}

\begin{lemma}[fifth lemma]
    This is a lemma, also.
\end{lemma}

\section{Alle wichtigen Definitionen und Lemmata}
\theoremlisttype{tab}
\listtheorems{defn,lemma}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: How can I modify this, so that for longer titles, this doesn't run over the edges?

Comment: Also, when copying your code into [an overleaf document](https://www.overleaf.com/4356288279jvkgdzkdjykr), it throws an error, do you know why?

Comment: Also, I changed the definition of the definition header font to \theoremheaderfont{\kern-5mm\bfseries\scshape} and removed it in the environment definition: \newshadedtheorem{defn}{Definition}[subsection], so that in this listing, the font of "Definition" is a normal one, like for the lemma.

Comment: Also, I wanted to use: \usepackage[bookmarks=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref} and even though I use \usepackage[thmmarks,framed,thref,hyperref]{ntheorem}, it still looks like this: lemma.1.1.1 Lemma & 1.1.\beta & second lemma.

Comment: I changed the code, so you get a linebreak in the tabular for long titles. I don't know why overleaf should throw an error. About hyperref look at section 3.4 of the documentation and maybe ask a new question for that one.

Comment: Is there a way to break over several pages? Mine just continues forever on a single page.

Comment: Use the `longtabular`environment.